# Python2 - IndexError: creating an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, input, raw-input

Well this is a piece of my script:

```
k = int(raw_input())
order = []
o = []
for i in range(1, k):
    o.append(raw_input())
    order.append([int(n) for n in list(o[i])])
```

and I've been getting the following error after these input lines:

```
3
241356789



 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line 11, in <module>
    order.append([int(n) for n in list(o[i])])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But I just cannot figure out why. Can anybody help me please? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: No, I didn't do that.

Comment: `i` starts at 1 (one), your first `append` adds an element to the list which is index 0 (zero), but you are attempting to index 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, `range(1, k)` (in Python 2) gives you a list `[1, 2, 3, ..., k-1]`.
When you append the list `o` by something from the input, the element is available on index `0`

```
>> o = []
>> o.append(42)
>> o[0]
42
```

But, in your loop you try to get index `1`, which is not available.

Remember, that the first element in a list is available through index `0`, where the second has index `1` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Python has a 0-based indexing.
Since you are effectively starting your loop from 1 instead of zero, the first call will exceed the existing list (which, at that point, has length `0` only).

Simply changing your line to

```
for i in range(0,k):
```

fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Index `i` starts with 1 (range(1,k)) but index `o` starts with 0. You can use o[-1] to access the last element. Or change the for loop to be `for i in range(k)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "1" from  `for i in range(1, k):` 
it worked fine for me with the line `for i in range(k):` you can do this in order to make one less loop `for i in range(k-1):`

Answer (score 0):

Smply put : `for i in range(0, k):` instead of `for i in range(1, k):` in order to begin from the start which is 0th index.